# Spark Python reduceByKey low performance

Tags: python, pyspark

Could you help me with the issue I met ? I am working on a 100Go file. I tried to run the following code :

```
testUP_TIME = (linesSampleMarch
           .filter(lambda x : x[0][0:10]=="2015-03-21")
           .map(lambda s : ((s[1], s[2]),1) )
           .reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x+y ))
           .groupByKey()
           .cache())
```

After a very long time (about 30'), it finally ended with an error : "An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.4 in stage 5.0 (TID 654, 192.168.161.52): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 9 lost)"

I found out that the reduceByKey() was responsible of it. Do you have any advice to optimize this query? I thought of increasing the number of partitions of the parent RDD but I don't know if I am right. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide an example for the data you are using and explain what are you trying to do?

I'm not sure I understand why you need to do groupByKey after the reduceByKey action.

But in general, the error you got can be an indicator for a lack of memory in the executor. Python uses some extra memory that spark can't account for.

The way to solve this is to enlarge `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`.

I use `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` similar in size to `executor-memory`.

Comment: Sorry there was one error in my code, I only had the reduceByKey. I finally managed to have my code running on my data by increasing the partitions in the reduceBeyKey from 8 (default) to 32. Thanks for you answer anyway!